# $\sqrt{1+x}$ as summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, exponentiation

I was reading [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2284406/pi-as-an-infinite-series-using-taylor-expansion-on-equation-of-a-circle) and there was something in the first answer (adfriedman's answer) that I didn't understand.

It states that:
$$
\int_0^1(1+(-x^2))^{1/2}dx = \int_0^1\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{1/2}{k}(-x^2)^k dx
$$
Which I assume gives:
$$
(1+(-x^2))^{1/2} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{1/2}{k}(-x^2)^k
$$
I have never seen this, and I couldn't find anything about it online, so I was wondering where this comes from. Could it possibly be generalised to:
$$
(1+a)^{b} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{b}{k}(a)^k
$$

If so, where does this come from? What's the intuition behind it? Why does it make sense?

Comment: The [binomial series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) is a generalization of the binomial theorem from algebra.

Comment: This is called Newton's binomial theorem.  It is also possible to obtain it as a Maclauren series.

Comment: So this only works when $|x|<1$?

Comment: Yeah, only $|x|<1.$ But here, that is also the only real domain of $(1-x^2)^{1/2}$

Comment: What about $(1-0^2)^{1/2} = 1$. Would it still work?

Comment: for k=0 it could be defined as 1

Comment: It's conventional to pick $0^0=1$ for series, for instance a common example is $e^0=\frac{0^0}{0!} =1$ is the first term.

Comment: But since it's being integrated, I would expect whether we include the 1 or not in integration to have no effect on the final result anyway.